# Is there a way to tell gradle to list all the dependencies present in a local repository?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, repository

I know that gradle let's you point to a specific local repository like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        // URL can refer to a local directory
        url "../local-repo"
    }
}
```

Example 7.7 in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html (I modified it to be maven in this case)

Now, does anybody knows if gradle has any capability to "browse" that local repository and return the full list of dependencies available in there?

I would like to be able to list those dependencies.

Comment: Why have gradle list them though? You can just browse through the repo on the file system..

Comment: BTW, m2eclipse comes with handy maven repo browser: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html

Comment: The thing is that I need to do it programatically. I would like to retrieve that list and populate that in my own UI.